# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "userName like %@ password like %@"'

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

### Heading

I am trying to fetch the data from sql file but I keep getting the NSInvalidArgumentException. 
I will really appreciate if somebody can help me figure out.

```
- (IBAction)signIn:(id)sender {
    //Creating a fetch request
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    //Create NSManagedObjectContext instance
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription  *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userName like %@ password like %@",self.username_signin.text, self.password_signin.text];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error;

}
```

Comment: You should show the full exception message and stack trace in the question.

Comment: Note also that passwords shouldn't be stored in core data as it generally isn't safe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format is wrong because it has two parts but you don't say how they should be combined. It should be something like:

```
userName like %@ AND password like %@
```

Also, you most likely should be using `=` instead of `like` because you want an exact match not a regex type match...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure.

This row

```
NSPredicate *predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userName like %@ password like %@",self.username_signin.text, self.password_signin.text];
```

change

```
NSPredicate *predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userName like %@ && password like %@",self.username_signin.text, self.password_signin.text];
```